# Button.PerformClick for labels?

Tags: vb.net, click

Basically what the title asks, is there any such thing for PerformClick but for labels? It seems to only work on buttons. :(
Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Labels do have [click events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553231.aspx)... If you want to perform the click you still can but your question lacks details. For example do you want to do this from a button event or some method? I would recommend updating your question with what you have tried and what's not working as this may be flagged to be closed.

Comment: Well, for the project I'm working on what I want to happen is that a button is pressed, and then that causes the label to be clicked on (which is the part where the PerformClick for labels would really come in handy). I don't really need label click events, I just need the label to be clicked after the button is pressed. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: `I don't really need label click events` yeah you do. You have to have the event in your class to be able to call it... For example `Label1_Click(Label1, Nothing)` this would work if you had a label with the name of Label1 and a click event named Label1_Click...

Comment: I do have click events for my labels, I had thought they were not needed for this task. Apologies for the misunderstanding- just saw your edit I'm trying it out

Comment: Add the code above I showed you to the button event. `Label1_Click(Label1, Nothing)` change the name to what your label click event is And the label name...ooo

Comment: The code works great! Much appreciated, you saved my cp grade :)

Comment: Welcome happy coding.

Comment: If you dont need to pass any sender or eventargs information to the code that is currently in the label.click event, you might be better moving the code into a separate sub. Then you can call the new sub from either the label.click event or from the button.click event.